# MYSQL Intervalo de hora

Tags: mysql

Preciso buscar em um servidor, através de um comando, um intervalo de 2 horas de um dado salvo em relação ao horário do servidor.

**Exemplo**: Um funcionário abre um chamado; esse chamado será salvo no banco na data X com o horário 12:00:00 e seu status ficará como "EM ABERTO". Eu preciso buscar todos os chamados que não foram solucionados em um intervalo de 2 horas.

```
SELECT datas FROM banco WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) <= datas AND status='2';
```

O objetivo deste comando é buscar no banco o horário dos chamados e comparar com a hora do sistema. Se passou de duas horas, irá mostrar, se não, não mostra.

Quando eu dou este comando, ele me mostra este dados,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O comando foi dado as 15:03, só que ele mostrou outros horários, além de 2 horas em aberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu select retorna isso pois `CURDATE` só retorna a data atual, sem o horário. Use `NOW()` no cálculo, pois ele retorna data e hora atuais:

```
SELECT datas FROM banco WHERE datas >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND status='2';
```